# Call REST Service from WebAPi and transfer HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have to call a REST Service from Web API.
Call and retrieve data works well but the return method crash.
I have tried several method that return an `async HttpResponseMessage`, but I can return this object as well (error socket on chrome ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR).
I've tried too with just a plain json as string, but no more success.

Here some tries :

```
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<JObject> Get(string id)
    {
        dynamic client = new RestClient($"https://...../accounts/{id}/summary",
            new Dictionary<string, string> {
                //some KVP for access Rest API
            });
//await client.Get() returns HttpResponseMessage 200 and Content is well populated

        JObject result =  JObject.FromObject(await client.Get());
        return result;
        //Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>());

        //HttpResponseMessage result = await client.Get(); => HttpResponseMessage is well filled
        //Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>()); => test with wrapping inside a new HttpResponseMessage but no more success



        //using (var client = new HttpClient())
        //{
        //    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://....../v1/accounts/{id}/summary");
        //    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        //    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        //    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        //    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.Content.ReadAsAsync());
        //}
    }
```

Is there a simple method to retrieve json from Rest Service and transfer this as it is ?

Comment: did you check the response status using response.IsSuccessStatusCode?

Comment: yes, it's Status Code = 200.

Comment: Are you able to parse the response from the REST Api call and get the object as the one you intended to? i.e. Is the data returned as per your need so that we can isolate the issue whether its the response you get or if there is any issue when sending out your response.

Comment: If you just want to transfer the json, it would be a waste to parse it first to an object and then write to json again. You could read the json as a stream and copy the stream to the output.

Comment: yes, this is my needs. I can retrieve the json but I'll like transfer this in a generic way. The goals is to have a proxy between public api and private api with credentials.

Comment: Could you possibly clean up the code in the main post to exactly what block of code it is you're using? Also, as W van said, it is a waste to parse/Deserialize the JSON only to Serialize it immediately when it's being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these calls are being performed in a Web API, and there is no logic being applied to the JSON Object, then there is little need to parse it before returning it as it will get serialized again when being returned, you can instead parse it on the front-end application and perform your logic there.

`HttpClient` has a method which returns the response body as a string, this is [`GetStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx). With the body returned as string, you can return that directly in your `HttpResponseMessage`

Here's an example using your `HttpClient` commented code.

```
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string id)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://....../v1/accounts/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Fetch the response body as a string
        // Resource URI added below
        string responseContent = await client.GetStringAsync($"{id}/summary");

        // Create our response object and set the content to its StringContent
        var response =
            new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new StringContent(responseContent)};

        // Return our HttpResponseMessage containing our json text
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but `{Content = new StringContent(responseContent)}` was the key to resend ResponseMessage.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to transfer the json response from another API, you can use code like the following in Web API:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("v1/test", Name = "test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder($"https://...../...");
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*";
        using (var jsonResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            var jsonStream = jsonResponse.GetResponseStream();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            jsonStream.CopyTo(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return response;
        }            
    }
```

When the only thing needed is to support authentication or authorization features, i would prefer to use an API manager and not maintain this kind of code myself.